# Can someone explicitely explain this part of the proof of the Universal Coefficient Theorem for Cohomology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, proof-explanation, homology-cohomology

From Rotman's Algebraic Topology:  I'm having trouble understanding this proof, in particular what's in the red box.  I don't really understand what it's saying, it seems to indicate that homology groups are cohomology groups when you manipulate the indexes.

Can someone explicitly explain what the red box is saying and how it implies the short exact sequence immediately after it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The short exact sequence after the box comes from the Universal Coefficient Theorem for homology.

The important part of the red box is that the complex $C_*$ consists
of **finitely-generated** free Abelian groups. If $C$ is a finitely-generated
free Abelian group, so is $\textrm{Hom}(C,\Bbb Z)$ but if $C$ is free
but not finitely-generated, then $\textrm{Hom}(C,\Bbb Z)$
won't be free. In this case $A^*$ is a complex of free Abelian groups,
to which one may apply the UCT.

Comment: How can the sequence come from the Universal Coefficient Theorem if the sequence is in terms of cohomology groups and the theorem is in terms of homology groups?

Comment: And why is it important that $A^*$ is a complex of free abelian groups?  The only prerequisites for the Universal Coefficient Theorem are that $X$ be a space, $G$ be an abelian group, and $n \ge 0$.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "$A*$ is a free Abelian complex, to which one may apply the UTC"?  I don't understand how you can apply the UTC to a complex from a homology group and get a cohomology group.

Comment: @OliverG See Theorem 9.32 in Rotman's book. He starts the proof by saying "We prove a more general result". This more general result is the real UCT which concerns chain complexes of free Abelian groups. This applies just as well to cochain complexes; the only difference between chain and cochain complexes is the labelling of the groups within.